# Discord Python Multithread Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I take user input from users on discord and use it for my function `check`. Though, the check function can take 30-50 seconds to complete each because it has to wait for websites to load etc. I am using requests.get. How can I make this multi threaded?

My current code:

```
import json
import discord
import os
import bs4
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import threading
import time
import re
from string import digits, ascii_letters

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
bot.remove_command('help')
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
url = 'hidden'
url2 = 'hidden'
url3 = 'hidden'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}

whitelist = set(digits + ascii_letters + "#_[] -")
blacklist = set("")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("It's ready")


@bot.command()
async def check(ctx, *args):
    #my very advanced code start
    response = ""
    start_time = time.time()
    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg
    #go on website and scrape with username 
    # my very advanced code end


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I am hiding most of my information in my function `check`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` and `urllib` are blocking. Do **not** use this libraries within your asynchronous code. Use `aiohttp` instead.

Here an example of code using `aiohttp` and `discord.py`

```py
import aiohttp

@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://httpbin.org/json') as r:
            res = await r.json()
```

> Don't create a session per request. Most likely you need a session per application which performs all requests altogether.

Here's how to keep one session that you can access from cogs/extensions/functions

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()


@bot.command()
async def bar(ctx):
    async with bot.session.get('https://httpbin.org/json') as r:
        res = await r.json()
```

But if you really want to use requests:

```py
def fetch():
    x = requests.get('https://httpsbin.org/json')
    return x.json()


# in your asynchronous code
response = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, fetch)
```

[`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very annoying to swap everything, but very worth it. A++